# Is it possible to make a client software by using C# as shell and rendering view by html + css?

Tags: c#, geckofx, web-container

I want to write a client software, that can be installed on user's desktop machine.
I want to write a shell in C# and involve GeckoFX as embedded WebBrowser to render view by using html + css.

The problem is, if i do like i said, i need a webcontainer to get those web pages run in.

My solution right now, is write a embedded tomcat. Package this embedded tomcat and war file and the C# stuff in the installation file, every time when end user launch the program, the C#  shell should create a new progress to start the embedded tomcat to provide the webservice. And  kill this progress when C# shell is shutting down.

I don't think it is a good way, but i am really new to this area, does anyone can help to suggest a better way? Thanks very much.

Comment: Well.. embed the CSS in HTML. With the MS WebBrowser you would do something like:

   ´WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html>...</html>";´
or if you like it complicated :
    ´webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
    webBrowser.Document.Write("<html>...</html>");´

Maybe you can give Gecko also a String (or a stream)?

Comment: The thing is, i know how to use GeckoFX to navigate to the url and display it. But it requires me to provide a webserver to expose webservice, right? So i have a embedded tomcat to run my war file to provide the functionality locally. But it seems not that professional, i prefer a better way than webcontainer. I am not sure that if i made myself clear. Anyway, thanks for reply.

Comment: I don'T know what you want to do with webservice... but it is simply to host a webservice ´Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:48080/TestService");
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyContract), baseAddress))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IYourContract), new NetTcpBinding(), "");
                host.Open();
                Console.ReadLine(); // keep the service open
                host.Close();}´ All you need is adress, binding, contract, so most work will be the interface of teh contract of the webservice.